# Could not download http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.13/node-v0.12.13-darwin-x64.tar.g

Tags: maven, proxy, npm, apache-zeppelin

I'm getting this error trying to build Zeppelin 0.6. on OS X 10.11.6

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project zeppelin-web: Could not download Node.js: Could not download http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.13/node-v0.12.13-darwin-x64.tar.gz: Connect to localhost:3128 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1] failed: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
```

Node.js:

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:zeppelin davidlaxer$ npm -version
2.15.8
```

Maven:

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:zeppelin davidlaxer$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /opt/local/share/java/maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac
```

I can manually run the npm command that is failing from the zeppelin/zeppelin-web subdirectory as root:

```
$ sudo npm install --color=false --proxy=http://localhost:3128
Password:
npm WARN package.json zeppelin-web@0.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"4.4.7","npm":"2.15.8"})
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as 'css-select'

> fsevents@1.0.14 install /Users/davidlaxer/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/davidlaxer/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'

> ws@0.4.32 install /Users/davidlaxer/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN cannot run in wd phantomjs@1.9.20 node install.js (wd=/Users/davidlaxer/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs)
grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy

karma-jasmine@0.1.6 node_modules/karma-jasmine

grunt-cache-bust@1.3.0 node_modules/grunt-cache-bust

grunt-newer@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-newer
├── async@0.2.10
└── rimraf@2.2.6

grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean
└── rimraf@2.2.8

grunt-karma@0.8.3 node_modules/grunt-karma
└── lodash@2.4.2

bower@1.7.2 node_modules/bower
└── semver-utils@1.1.1

jshint-stylish@0.2.0 node_modules/jshint-stylish
├── text-table@0.2.0
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

time-grunt@0.3.2 node_modules/time-grunt
├── date-time@0.1.1
├── pretty-ms@0.1.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── text-table@0.2.0
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-filerev@0.2.1 node_modules/grunt-filerev
├── each-async@0.1.3
└── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-contrib-concat@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat
└── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-concurrent@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-concurrent
├── async@0.2.10
└── pad-stdio@0.1.1 (lpad@0.2.1)

load-grunt-tasks@0.4.0 node_modules/load-grunt-tasks
├── multimatch@0.1.0 (lodash@2.4.2, minimatch@0.2.14)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)

grunt-cli@0.1.13 node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.9)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)

grunt-usemin@2.6.2 node_modules/grunt-usemin
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
└── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)

autoprefixer@6.4.0 node_modules/autoprefixer
├── normalize-range@0.1.2
├── num2fraction@1.2.2
├── postcss-value-parser@3.3.0
├── browserslist@1.3.5
├── caniuse-db@1.0.30000518
└── postcss@5.1.2 (js-base64@2.1.9, source-map@0.5.6, supports-color@3.1.2)

grunt-postcss@0.7.2 node_modules/grunt-postcss
├── es6-promise@3.2.1
├── diff@2.2.3
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)
└── postcss@5.1.2 (js-base64@2.1.9, source-map@0.5.6, supports-color@3.1.2)

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.9
├── async@0.1.22
├── colors@0.6.2
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.9)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.2, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.7.3)
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3 (grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1, lodash@2.4.2, underscore.string@2.3.3)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.16)

grunt-svgmin@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-svgmin
├── each-async@0.1.3
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.2
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── svgo@0.4.5 (colors@0.6.2, whet.extend@0.9.9, sax@0.6.1, coa@0.4.1, js-yaml@2.1.3)

grunt-contrib-connect@0.7.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect
├── async@0.2.10
├── connect-livereload@0.3.2
├── open@0.0.4
├── portscanner@0.2.2 (async@0.1.15)
└── connect@2.13.1 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, debug@0.8.1, qs@0.6.6, pause@0.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, raw-body@1.1.3, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, bytes@0.2.1, batch@0.5.0, compressible@1.0.0, cookie@0.1.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)

grunt-ng-annotate@0.10.0 node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate
├── ng-annotate@0.15.4 (tryor@0.1.2, stringset@0.2.1, stringmap@0.2.2, simple-fmt@0.1.0, simple-is@0.2.0, alter@0.2.0, stable@0.1.5, convert-source-map@0.4.1, optimist@0.6.1, source-map@0.1.43, acorn@0.11.0, ordered-ast-traverse@1.1.1)
└── lodash.clonedeep@3.0.2 (lodash._bindcallback@3.0.1, lodash._baseclone@3.3.0)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch
├── async@0.2.10
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, qs@0.5.6, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3)
└── gaze@0.5.2 (globule@0.1.0)

grunt-angular-templates@0.5.9 node_modules/grunt-angular-templates
└── html-minifier@0.6.9 (relateurl@0.2.7, clean-css@2.2.23, change-case@2.1.6, cli@0.6.6, uglify-js@2.4.24)

grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.3.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.2
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── html-minifier@0.6.9 (relateurl@0.2.7, clean-css@2.2.23, change-case@2.1.6, cli@0.6.6, uglify-js@2.4.24)

grunt-goog-webfont-dl@0.1.2 node_modules/grunt-goog-webfont-dl
├── lodash@3.10.1
└── goog-webfont-dl@0.1.1 (commander@2.6.0, async@0.9.2, lodash@3.1.0, css@2.1.0, request@2.53.0)

grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.9.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── clean-css@2.1.8 (commander@2.1.0)
└── maxmin@0.1.0 (pretty-bytes@0.1.2, gzip-size@0.1.1)

grunt-wiredep@2.0.0 node_modules/grunt-wiredep
└── wiredep@2.2.2 (propprop@0.3.1, minimist@1.2.0, lodash@2.4.2, chalk@0.5.1, through2@0.6.5, bower-config@0.5.2, glob@4.5.3)

grunt-dom-munger@3.4.0 node_modules/grunt-dom-munger
└── cheerio@0.12.4 (entities@0.5.0, underscore@1.4.4, htmlparser2@3.1.4, cheerio-select@0.0.3)

grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
├── hooker@0.2.3
└── jshint@2.5.11 (underscore@1.6.0, strip-json-comments@1.0.4, exit@0.1.2, minimatch@1.0.0, shelljs@0.3.0, console-browserify@1.1.0, cli@0.6.6, htmlparser2@3.8.3)

karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── phantomjs@1.9.20 (progress@1.1.8, kew@0.7.0, which@1.2.10, request-progress@2.0.1, hasha@2.2.0, extract-zip@1.5.0, fs-extra@0.26.7, request@2.67.0)

grunt-contrib-uglify@0.4.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify
├── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── maxmin@0.1.0 (pretty-bytes@0.1.2, gzip-size@0.1.1)
└── uglify-js@2.7.0 (async@0.2.10, uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, source-map@0.5.6, yargs@3.10.0)

karma@0.12.37 node_modules/karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── q@1.4.1
├── mime@1.3.4
├── graceful-fs@3.0.8
├── colors@1.1.2
├── lodash@3.10.1
├── useragent@2.1.9 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── source-map@0.4.4 (amdefine@1.0.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)
├── glob@5.0.15 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, inflight@1.0.5, once@1.3.3)
├── rimraf@2.5.4 (glob@7.0.5)
├── log4js@0.6.38 (semver@4.3.6, readable-stream@1.0.34)
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (colors@0.6.2, pkginfo@0.3.1, utile@0.2.1)
├── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
├── connect@2.30.2 (cookie@0.1.3, bytes@2.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.6, utils-merge@1.0.0, on-headers@1.0.1, pause@0.1.0, content-type@1.0.2, fresh@0.3.0, parseurl@1.3.1, vhost@3.0.2, response-time@2.3.1, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, cookie-parser@1.3.5, depd@1.0.1, qs@4.0.0, connect-timeout@1.6.2, debug@2.2.0, method-override@2.3.6, serve-favicon@2.3.0, http-errors@1.3.1, multiparty@3.3.2, type-is@1.6.13, finalhandler@0.4.0, morgan@1.6.1, express-session@1.11.3, serve-static@1.10.3, serve-index@1.7.3, errorhandler@1.4.3, compression@1.5.2, body-parser@1.13.3, csurf@1.8.3)
└── chokidar@1.6.0 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, glob-parent@2.0.0, async-each@1.0.0, is-binary-path@1.0.1, is-glob@2.0.1, fsevents@1.0.14, readdirp@2.1.0, anymatch@1.3.0)

karma-coverage@0.5.5 node_modules/karma-coverage
├── source-map@0.5.6
├── minimatch@3.0.2 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)
├── dateformat@1.0.12 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.7.0)
└── istanbul@0.4.4 (abbrev@1.0.9, async@1.5.2, wordwrap@1.0.0, nopt@3.0.6, esprima@2.7.2, mkdirp@0.5.1, resolve@1.1.7, which@1.2.10, once@1.3.3, supports-color@3.1.2, js-yaml@3.6.1, escodegen@1.8.1, fileset@0.2.1, handlebars@4.0.5)
```

But the mvn command fails:

```
[INFO] Downloading Node.js from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.13/node-v0.12.13-darwin-x64.tar.gz to /Users/davidlaxer/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node_tmp/node.tar.gz
[INFO] Downloading via proxy proxy-http{protocol='http', host='localhost', port=3128}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [  3.336 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.025 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-07T00:02:45-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/115M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "spark-2.0" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "hadoop-2.6" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project zeppelin-web: Could not download Node.js: Could not download http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.13/node-v0.12.13-darwin-x64.tar.gz: Connect to localhost:3128 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1] failed: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I tried following the proxy adjustments listed on the github Zeppelin repository:

```
Proxy settings (optional)

First of all, set your proxy configuration on Maven settings.xml.

<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy-http</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <!-- <username>usr</username>
      <password>pwd</password> -->
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy-https</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <!-- <username>usr</username>
      <password>pwd</password> -->
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
Then, run these commands from shell.

npm config set proxy http://localhost:3128
npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:3128
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set strict-ssl false
git config --global http.proxy http://localhost:3128
git config --global https.proxy http://localhost:3128
git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://
Cleanup: set active false in Maven settings.xml and run these commands.

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset url."http://".insteadOf
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to set 'active' to false in ~/.m2/settings.xml before running:

Cleanup: set active false in Maven settings.xml and run these commands.

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset url."http://".insteadOf

Comment: I didn't follow exactly what you have instructed but your answer guided me the way to approach. Thanks